# How many bytes does a specific integer require at runtime?

Tags: java, memory, binary, int, byte

This is likely to be a duplicate question, but I was unable to find a similar one when searching.

I'm looking for an easy, efficient method to determine how many signed bytes an `int` requires at runtime.

For example, consider an `int` with the following values:

```
1     - Requires 1 Byte
10    - Requires 1 Byte
128   - Requires 2 Bytes
1024  - Requires 2 Bytes
32768 - Requires 3 Bytes
...
Integer.MAX_VALUE - Requires 4 Bytes
```

Edit: It's obvious to me that an `int` requires 4 `byte`s of memory regardless of its value.  Nevertheless, I'm looking for the amount of bytes that the value would take up if that wasn't the case.

**Ideally the answer I'm looking for utilizes bit manipulation and returns a value of 1 for an input of 0.**

Comment: Bytes are 8 bits.  You need to identify how many bits your number needs.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm looking to identify how many `byte`s my number needs.

Comment: In Java, an `int` always needs 4 bytes of memory, regardless of its contents.

Comment: @Alnitak I know, but I'm looking for the exact amount of bytes the number takes up regardless.

Comment: Do you consider negative numbers?

Comment: @apilat Not in my specific use-case, but it would be nice if the solution handled them properly.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know where the highest-set bit is? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#highestOneBit(int) or `(hsb+7)/8`, to get the number of bytes.

Comment: What do you intend to use this information for?

Comment: @AndyTurner I assume that method can be used in the solution, but I'm looking for a value (1 through 4) that represents the amount of bytes an arbitrary number would require (within `int` bounds).

Comment: @Kayaman I'm adding an integer to a `ByteBuffer`, but I want to be exact regarding memory requirements depending on the value of the `int`, as I don't plan to add all 4 bytes if the value only requires 1.

Comment: @JacobG. the `(hsb + 7) / 8` method would actually return exactly that (except that it returns 0 for 0, not 1)

Comment: @Alnitak I see.  For my case, a value of 0 would need to return 1.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think `highestOneBit()` returns the bit position. It returns value with the highest bit set.

Comment: Ideally the answer I'm looking for utilizes bit manipulation and returns a value of 1 for an input of 0.

Comment: @shmosel good point...

Comment: When you've added 4 1-byte values to the buffer, how do you know if it's 4, 2 or 1 value? How can you use those values?

Comment: @Kayaman also a good question - you can't just wire encode stuff into a buffer like that without being able to figure out how to get it back out again.

Comment: @Kayaman If you're really interested: http://wiki.vg/Protocol#VarInt_and_VarLong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One line solution according to your requirements:

```
public int bytesCount(int n) {
    return n < 0 ? 4 : (32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)) / 8 + 1;
}
```

Where `32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)` returns the position of the highest one-bit. After that you can easily calculate the number of required bytes.

Comment: This was what I was looking for, as it works with signed `byte` values.  Thank you!

Comment: You may want to check the implementation of `numberOfLeadingZeros()` to ensure that it is better than what you had already.  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone has a much more efficient way to do this but a simple and easy to understand this is see what the upper bound power of 2 is higher than it, thus you now how many bits it would fit in, then you can divide by 8 to figure out how many bytes you would need.

```
int bytesInInt(int i) {
    int exp = 0;
    while (Math.pow(2,exp) < i) {
        exp++;
    }
    return ((exp + 1) / 8) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it against the boundaries of numbers which can be stored in 1 byte (`byte`), 2 bytes (`short`), 3 bytes.

```
int bytes_needed(int n){
    if(n >= -128 && n <= 127){
        return 1;
    } else if(n >= -32768 && n <= 32767){
        return 2;
    } else if(n >= -8388608 && n <= 8388607){
        return 3;
    } else {
        return 4;
    }
}
```